# W3 total cache - white screen of death when trying to show certain taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, plugin-w3-total-cache

I'm using plugin W3 Total cache and it worked excellent -until I added a custom "detail page" of a custom taxonomy (with a file called taxonomy-categorycourses.php) where the categorycourses is the taxonomy. I get the white screen of death-experience. I have turned errors on, but nothing shows up. I just get a blank page. I've google around and cannot find some satisfying answers. (The taxonomies shows up correctly when not cached , for example - when logged in).

**UPDATE**

I loved w3 total cache until know. This is a bug that shouldn't exist in the plugin, but it apprently does so I deleted it, and installed WP Super Cache and activated and then everything worked as it should.

Comment: Add your update as an answer and come back in two days and accept your own answer

Comment: Ok fixed that now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I loved w3 total cache until know. This is a bug that really shouldn't exist in the plugin, but it apprently does so I deleted it, and installed WP Super Cache and activated and then everything worked as it should.

Comment: If there is a bug in the plugin, you should contact the author author of the plugin with the full details of the bug. This way you will make a contribution to make good plugins great.